# Wigner Seitz cell

Tags: condensed-matter, crystals, lattice-model

While searching the difference between primitive cell and unit cell I have seen that "Primitive unit cells contain only one lattice point, which is made up from the lattice points at each of the corners."
Wigner Seitz cell is an example of primitive cell. But its lattice points are not at the corners of the cell. How this contradiction occurred? Is the property above is wrong or is there any other concept behind this which I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining Primitive unit cells as

> cells containing only one lattice point, which is made up from the
>   lattice points at each of the corners.

is reductive. The reason is the in the context of crystalline solid state physics, the underlying Bravais lattice structure, in $D$-dimensions,  defines a group of symmetry translations which are integer multiple of $D$ independent elementary translations, **with a completely arbitrary  choice of the origin**. More formally, once one has chosen  an origin and a set of $D$ basis vectors ${\bf a}_i$, all vectors 
$$
{\bf R}_{n_1,n_2,\dots,n_D}( {\bf \tau} ) = \sum _{i=1}^D n_i {\bf a}_i + {\bf \tau} , ~~~~n_i \epsilon {\mathbb Z}
$$
with ${\bf \tau}=\sum _{i=1}^D \lambda_i {\bf a}_i$, $0\leq\lambda_i<1$ provide the same description of the translational symmetry of the Bravais lattice.

Therefore, the primitive unit cell may be chosen with the original set of lattice points at the corners but other choices are equally possible. So, there is no contradiction with the Wigner-Seitz cell definition. If one likes, after choosing a given set of lattice points to build the W-S cell with the usual construction, thus ending with a primitive  cell with a lattice point at the center, one can translate the origin to "move" that lattice point in any other point of the cell, corners included.